# Best way to check JavaScript object's value if object may be undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `textarea` that I have a blur event attached to. I don't want the blur event to run if the user clicks on a specific `span.dontClick` on the page. However if the user clicks on anything other than the `span.dontClick` I do want the blur event to run. I have found a way to do this, but it looks awful, feels very hackey, and I'm guessing there is a better solution out there. Here's what I've come up with:

```
if (event.type === 'focusout') {
  if (
    typeof event.originalEvent !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof event.originalEvent.currentTarget !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof event.originalEvent.currentTarget.activeElement !== 'undefined' &&
    typeof event.originalEvent.currentTarget.activeElement.className !== 'undefined' &&
    event.originalEvent.currentTarget.activeElement.className === 'dontClick'
  ) {
    // abort the code for the blur event (in effect, do nothing)
  }
  else {
    // run code for when a user blurs by not clicking on span
  }
```

It should probably be noted that the `event` object is from a jQuery event handler. I'm not sure if it is different or the same as the native `event` objects.

It should also be noted that this fails silently for most browsers but I get a debug window in IE if I don't specify the 'undefined' state for each object all the way down the line...

If anyone has a more elegant solution I would really appreciate seeing it. Thanks!

Comment: This is one of the biggest reasons why [I love CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#try:if%20event.type%20%3D%3D%20'focusout'%0A%20%20if%20event.originalEvent%3F.currentTarget%3F.activeElement%3F.className%20%3D%3D%20'dontClick'%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20abort%20the%20code%20for%20the%20blur%20event%20(in%20effect%2C%20do%20nothing)%0A%20%20%0A%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20run%20code%20for%20when%20a%20user%20blurs%20by%20not%20clicking%20on%20span) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need comparisons to `undefined`. Just do a truthy test. Also the test for the `className` isn't needed. The `===` comparison will cover it.

```
 if (
    event.originalEvent &&
    event.originalEvent.currentTarget &&
    event.originalEvent.currentTarget.activeElement &&
    event.originalEvent.currentTarget.activeElement.className === 'dontClick'
  ) {
```

---

but then you're doing more work than needed anyway since jQuery gives you a reliable `currentTarget`.

```
 if (
    event.currentTarget.activeElement &&
    event.currentTarget.activeElement.className === 'dontClick'
  ) {
```

---

or if you're in a handler, just use `this`.

```
 if (this.activeElement && this.activeElement.className === 'dontClick') {
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any `activeElement` object under `event.currentTarget`, plus, if I'm thinking clearly about this, the reason I'm checking `event.originalEvent.currentTarget.activeElement.className` is because I need to see if a user clicked on the span originally. If it existed, wouldn't `event.currentTarget.activeElement` refer to the `textarea`?

Comment: @jasonmerino: Yes, the correct property is `document.activeElement`, and it would refer to the textarea. I wasn't sure why you were checking it for the class of the span. You could put a handler on the `span.dontClick`, but by the time it fires, the `blur` will have already fired. Perhaps the only way would be to have the `blur` event code in a short `setTimeout`, then have a click event on the `span.dontClick` set some global variable that the blur event can check before it invokes its code.

Comment: Yeah, I could set a timer, but to me that feels even more hackey than my current solution... :S

Comment: @jasonmerino: Yeah, it's pretty hackey, but it's tough to get around the fact that events happen in a certain order.